# Which variables in dataset are constant within id

Tags: r, data.table

I've got a data set with a bunch of near-duplicate observations for each individual. I'm trying to determine exactly which variables are changing across rows for each specific ID.

I started by inspection:

```
dt[ , count := .N, by = id][count > 1, ]
```

(also using `head` and `tail`), but there are 27000 (total) repeated observations--there's no way by inspection to be sure which variables are changing.

Is there anything better than the brute force approach?
In particular I'm hoping to avoid a loop but I can't see how...

```
dt[ , count := .N, by = id]
for (var in setdiff(names(dt), c("id", "count"))){
  if (nrow(dt[ , list(.N, count), by = c("id", var)][N < count, ]) > 0){
    print(var)
  }
}
```

## EDIT

Here's an example data set to clarify:

```
set.seed(2304)
DT <- data.table(a = rep(sample(5), each = 3),
                 b = sample(15),
                 c = rep(LETTERS[1:5], each = 3),
                 d = rnorm(15),
                 e = rep(6:10, each = 3),
                 f = 15:1,
                 grp = paste0("Group ", rep(1:5, each = 3)))
```

Desired output:

```
c("a", "c", "e")
```

because those variables don't change for *any* fixed value of `grp`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's pretend that `mtcars$carb` is our `id`.  Then, for each number of each id, we want to find out how many distinct `gear` values there are:

```
data.table(mtcars)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) length(unique(x))), by=carb]
```

Produces

```
   carb mpg cyl disp hp drat wt qsec vs am gear
1:    4   8   2    8  7    8  9   10  2  2    3
2:    1   7   2    7  6    6  7    7  1  2    2
3:    2   9   2   10  8    9 10   10  2  2    3
4:    3   3   1    1  1    1  3    3  1  1    1
5:    6   1   1    1  1    1  1    1  1  1    1
6:    8   1   1    1  1    1  1    1  1  1    1
```

Any variable with value > 1 has changing values for each `carb` value.

---

Edit:

Alternatively, we could expand this by running:

```
data.table(mtcars)[,lapply(.SD,uniqueN),by=carb
                   ][,!"carb"][,lapply(.SD,table)]

   mpg cyl disp hp drat wt qsec vs am gear
1:   2   3    3  3    3  2    2  4  3    3
2:   1   3    1  1    1  1    1  2  3    1
3:   1   3    1  1    1  1    1  4  3    2
4:   1   3    1  1    1  1    2  2  3    3
5:   1   3    3  3    3  1    2  4  3    1
```

This has the advantage (not apparent with this sample data set) that a given column is constant within the ID (`carb` here) ONLY IF the output of the above code is constant and equal to `length(unique(id))` in the corresponding column. There are 6 values of `carb`, so we can see that *none* of the variables in `mtcars` are constant within `carb`. Further, if we have a lot of IDs (I have >50,000 in a current example), the above approach will be much harder to interpret directly.

Sticking with `mtcars`, we can see that there are a few variables that are constant within `disp`:

```
data.table(mtcars)[,lapply(.SD,uniqueN),by=disp
                   ][,!"disp"][,lapply(.SD,table)]

   mpg cyl hp drat wt qsec vs am gear carb
1:  24  27 26   26 24   23 27 27   27   26
2:   2  27  1    1  2    3 27 27   27    1
3:   1  27 26   26  1    1 27 27   27   26
```

Hence, `vs`, `am`, and `gear` are constant within `disp`.

Comment: however, your first approach suggests something (i haven't tested yet) which should work along the lines of: `dt[,lapply(.SD,function(x){length(unique(x))}),by=id,.SDcols=setdiff(names(dt),"id")]`

Comment: For the OP's case, I think the answer is similar: `DT[,c(.N,lapply(.SD,function(x)length(unique(x)))),by=carb]`

Comment: @MichaelChirico `.SDcols` isn't needed, since the `by` column is left out by default.

Comment: Updated as per @Franks suggestion.

Comment: Oh, one other thing, I think it's good to have `.N` there as well, to tell you how many "duplicates" are associated with each id.

Comment: great! clean and simple. i had `lapply` in mind but was drawing a blank for the second half.

Comment: @BrodieG In `data.table_1.9.5` this could be simplified with `uniqueN`. ie. `as.data.table(mtcars)[, lapply(.SD, uniqueN), by=carb]`

Comment: @akrun, nice.  I was looking for exactly that function in base R but couldn't find it.

Comment: @BrodieG A similar option in `dplyr` is `n_distinct` i.e. `mtcars %>% group_by(carb) %>% summarise_each(funs(n_distinct))`

Comment: coming back to this issue, I think this answer is actually incomplete. I'm working now with a table with 130 columns -- poring over the answer to the approach here is a bit tedious. the problem is my fix doesn't work: `data.table(mtcars)[,lapply(.SD,uniqueN),by=disp][,!"disp",with=F][,lapply(.SD,function(x)if(all(x==1))x)]` is an error.

Comment: Any better suggestion than making the last `[]` into: `[,mget(names(.SD)[sapply(.SD,function(x) all(x==1))])]`?

Answer (score 0):

Michael, still not 100% clear exactly what you're after, so I'll propose three different solutions, starting with all columns that have at least one group with unique values:

```
names(
  Filter(
    identity,
    colSums(MT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) uniqueN(x) == .N), by=disp])  
) )[-1]

# [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"
```

All columns that have unique values for every group

```
names(
  Filter(
    `!`,
    colSums(MT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) uniqueN(x) != .N), by=disp])  
) )

# [1] "qsec"
```

All variables that are completely duplicated within each group:

```
names(
  Filter(
    identity,
    lapply(
      MT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) uniqueN(x) == 1), by=disp][, -1], 
      all
) ) )

# [1] "cyl"  "vs"   "am"   "gear"
```

Note that there is overlap between all three because of the special case where group size == 1 can be interpreted as either being completely unique or completely duplicated.  That should be easy to disamgiuate depending on what you want by modifying the function used within the data table call.